# Help make an equation where x becomes 0 with configurable curvature and period constants.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Please help me make an equation for a configurable game mod which governs how the player bleeds out over time.

## Variables

- $x$: player health
- $t$: time
- $x_\text{Max}$: maximum health

##### (Configurable constants..)

- $SUD$: seconds until death. Ex: $60$
- $SBF$: start bleed fraction. Defines at what fraction of $x_\text{Max}$ that bleeding should begin. Ex: $0.3$
- $CC$: curvature constant. Negative values should make $dx$ grow as $x$ approaches $0$, and positive values should make $dx$ shrink as $x$ approaches $0$.

## My equation so far..

$$dx = \frac{dt}{SUD}\cdot SBF \cdot x_\text{Max} $$

.. It works fine, but there is no $CC$. How can I add it to the equation?